# How to substitute method name and object name in Logger Statements in scala

Tags: scala, log4j, slf4j

```
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
object add {
  private val LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass)
   def addAll() {
LOGGER.info("Start addAll for add Object")
}
}
```

In the logger statment I don't want to hard code  **addALL** method  and **add** class. How can I
provide a substitution for these In logger statement with take care of perfomance overhead.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to configure logback file something like below.

```
<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
        <level>INFO</level>
    </filter>
     <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level  %class{36}.%M %L  - %msg%n</pattern>
     </encoder>
</appender>
```

You can have a look at [Logback doc](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html)